# Display last modified time of JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I am developing a webapp and the browser doesn't consistently empty the cache each time I refresh, so sometimes I'm not getting the latest version of my JavaScript file loaded.

I would like to have a console message indicating if I'm using the latest version of the JavaScript file each time I refresh. I'm thinking that displaying the "last modified" time of the JavaScript file will do the job!

Any thoughts? Is there a standard solution to my problem that I've missed?

Comment: IIRC JavaScript has no actual access to the files of the server, so you'll have to use AJAX with a server-side script such as PHP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For production environments, whenever you modify your script file, you can alter your script tags to include a version querystring, so that the browser sees there is a new version and gets a fresh copy from the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/myscript.js?v1"></script>
```

This is just a simple trick that gives the browser a url it hasn't seen before, forcing it to request the new file.  The server ignores the querystring and just returns the script file.

For development environments, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> to force the browser to fetch a fresh copy from the server.

Answer (score 0):

My standard solution for this kind of a problem (if I do understand your concern correctly), is to check the Net tab on the firebug. Go to the Js sub-tab, and then you will see the list of js files being requested from the server/cached. just check the response header.

look at the other answer here. Always use ctrl + f5 to refresh your browser (if you want fresh copy from the serer).

Comment: Do you know if something similar exists for Google Chrome developer tools?

Comment: there is firebug lite, but sadly the tools that you need, which is Net panel is not avilable there.

Comment: @Randomblue, The network tab in chrome tools has all this information.

Comment: @washwithcare: oh yeah, jeez i rarely used that one P